# How to pass HTML(View) Table data to controller to save in slq table

Tags: asp.net-core

I am calculating the some values based on data available for previous month and displaying in table format in view. I have another model where I need to pass these values and save in database. I am not inputting any value, either values are static or calculated. Values are not passed from view to controller.

I have tried the jquery/ajax but not successful.

//Controller//

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Proccess(List<ServerCount> deviceCounts)
        {
            if(deviceCounts == null)
            {
                deviceCounts = new List<ServerCount>();
            }

            var startOfTthisMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,
                DateTime.Today.Month, 1);
            var FromDate = startOfTthisMonth.AddMonths(-1);
            var ToDate = startOfTthisMonth.AddDays(-1);
            var billMonth = startOfTthisMonth.AddMonths(-1).ToString("MMM") + "-" + startOfTthisMonth.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy");

            ServerCount model = new ServerCount();

            foreach (ServerCount sc in deviceCounts)
            {
                model.BillingMonth = billMonth;
                model.ServiceName = sc.ServiceName;
                model.BaslineVol = sc.BaslineVol;
                model.ResourceUnit = sc.ResourceUnit;
                model.DeviceCount = sc.DeviceCount;
                model.DeployedServer = sc.DeployedServer;
                model.RetiredServer = sc.RetiredServer;
                _context.ServerCount.Add(model);
            }

            int insertRecords = _context.SaveChanges();

            return Json(insertRecords);
        }

==================
Jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
            var deviceCounts = new Array();
            $("#tblServerCount TBODY TR").each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                var deviceCount = {};
                deviceCount.ServiceName = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
                deviceCount.BaslineVol = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                deviceCount.ResourceUnit = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
                deviceCount.DeviceCount = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
                deviceCount.DeployedServer = row.find("TD").eq(4).html();
                deviceCount.RetiredServer = row.find("TD").eq(5).html();
                deviceCounts.push(deviceCount);
            });

            var model = $("#MyForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Proccess", "DeviceCountServers", new { Area = "Admin" })?' +model,
                data: JSON.stringify(deviceCounts),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
                    location.reload();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I looking that data from table is saved to sql on click of button

Comment: why are you doing '@Url.Action("Proccess", "DeviceCountServers", new { Area = "Admin" })?' +model <<<< with the model? you are affectively sending it to a URL that doesn't exist. with a break point set in the method do you actually arrive into that method call?

Comment: This was the last hope to make it work but it didn't work out

Comment: Remove that `+model`, place a breakpoint, see if the actual call to `Proccess` occurs, if it doesn't means the signature is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Removed +model, applied break point. It seems nothing to work out. array is not passed. Anyone can help me with simple code to make it working.